# Spring Web Service Pre Authentication Filter Map Roles

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security, pre-authentication

I am trying to configure pre authentication for my spring web service with tomcat authentication. I tried pre-auth spring sample and configured my applicationContext-security.xml like below to use default spring configuration.

```
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <sec:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="sif,j2eePreAuthFilter,logoutFilter,etf,fsi"/>
    </sec:filter-chain-map>
</bean>

<bean id="sif" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter"/>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref='preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider'/>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" ref="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedGrantedAuthoritiesUserDetailsService"/>

<bean id="j2eePreAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationDetailsSource">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eeBasedPreAuthenticatedWebAuthenticationDetailsSource">
            <property name="mappableRolesRetriever">
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.WebXmlMappableAttributesRetriever" />
            </property>
            <property name="userRoles2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper">
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAttributes2GrantedAuthoritiesMapper">
                    <property name="convertAttributeToUpperCase" value="true"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint"/>

<bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg value="/"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="servletContext" class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextFactoryBean"/>

<bean id="etf" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="preAuthenticatedProcessingFilterEntryPoint"/>
</bean>

<bean id="httpRequestAccessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions" value="false"/>
    <property name="decisionVoters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="roleVoter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="fsi" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="httpRequestAccessDecisionManager"/>
    <property name="securityMetadataSource">
        <sec:filter-invocation-definition-source>
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="TESTROLE"/>
        </sec:filter-invocation-definition-source>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>

<bean id="securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter"/>
```

Here TESTROLE is a role defined in tomcat-users.xml
but now I get the below error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [TESTROLE]
    org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:156)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:379)
```

Any I ideas why this is happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was simply a mistake on role definition. For `spring-security` to identity roles they need to start with `ROLE_` so I simply change my role to `ROLE_TEST`. And finally it worked. :)